# Is it possible to deploy Firebase functions outside of Google Cloud?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'd like to implement a full text search an app that is using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/).

[Integrating with Algolia](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search) sounds great, but it can't work on the free Spark plan since outbound networking is limited to Google services only.

Therefore, the obvious question:

(1) Is it possible to use [`firebase-functions`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-functions) to create a function that monitors Firestore changes and deploy it to something like [Zeit's Lambda](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/deployments/concepts/lambdas) or [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/)?

Somewhat related question:

(2) Is it possible to use [`onSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#onSnapshot) instead of [`onCreate`/`onUpdate`/etc.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function) to monitor Firestore changes?

Answer (score 1):

You can't deploy Cloud Functions code to other serverless function providers.  You can certainly try to reuse your core logic, but each provider has its own APIs and infrastructure, and firebase-functions only knows how to work with Cloud Functions.

Comment: Thanks @Doug. Any thoughts on (2)?

Comment: Could you elaborate, please? 
If I have a node process running with `onSnapshot` subscription on a collection, how is it conceptually different from having `onCreate`/`onUpdate`/etc. subscriptions? What's the biggest downside of using `onSnapshot`?